# Combine different Excel files in Power BI

Tags: excel

I have two Excel files, 'PROJECTS' and 'PAYMENTS'.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to combine them in Power BI (the 'Project_no' should be as a common field)?

I tried this way:

```
Get Data => More => Folder => Combine & Transform Data
```

But got the following error message:

[image]

What I did wrong?

Comment: I don't see any code or information that shows how you loaded the two files and set their data types.

Answer (score 0):

Load in the two tables, then when you're in the Model tab, select `Manage Relationships` then select `New`.

Choose the two tables and the columns that connects them, then determine the Cardinality (is it 1:1 or 1 to many, etc.) and you should be able to interact with the two tables as if they were one. No coding needed.